Can I travel to India if my passport expires in 25 March 2025?
I am an Indian passport holder, currently in the Netherlands.
I wanted to travel back to India permanently on 24 January 2025. My passport is going to expire on 25 March 2025.
Can I travel back to India without any issues?

Rules requiring passport validity for X months only apply for entering foreign countries, not returning to your own country. As long as your passport has not expired, and you don't enter any countries along the way (airside transit is OK), you will be fine.
That said, I note that you have tagged both air-india and emirates in your question. If you buy two separate tickets and transfer in Dubai, you will need a UAE visa and passport validity rules apply. So be sure to buy a single connecting ticket.

Do you have rules and government guideline for this?

@BinduPaul As a citizen of India, you have an absolute right to return to India.

Is there any chances/possibilities in Schiphol airport Amsterdam while checkin they stop me to return india on 24 January 2025 ? As my passport expires on 25 March 2025?

@BinduPaul No. You are an Indian citizen with a valid passport, you are allowed to return to India. You don't need a visa and it's no problem if your passport expires after you have arrived, you can get a new one.

I would still recommend coming to the airport earlier than usual, just in case you have to escalate things for example if an overmotivated trainee needs some adjustments.

@Iambshaanxy thank you so much for the confirmation

@BinduPaul Please accept the answer (click the ✔️ mark) if it answered your question!

@WeatherVane You'll get in if you can make it to the border, but most airlines will not let you fly with one.

@WeatherVane- your comment again confused me. Again thinking should i go with renew passport process, which is very tough because i want to travel back to india permanently on 24 January 2025. And my passport will expire on 25 March 2025.

@BinduPaul There is absolutely no need to renew your passport, it's fine for returning to India.

The customs will let you through: your passport is valid for your home country up until its expiration date.
However, some online airline booking systems will require passport validity for 3 or 6 months to sell you a ticket. So your travel options might be limited. Check if you can get a ticket. If you can't, call the airline's ticket office and ask them for directions.
Direct flights, especially by airlines from your home nation, will almost always work, but indirect flights might have issues with booking or boarding, as the airlines may worry about fines if you're refused entry at any point.
If there's no way to get a ticket (unlikely), or if you stay longer and your passport expires, your country's consulate can provide a replacement travel document, which will be accepted for any direct flight home. (With connections, same issues as an expiring passport - legally valid, but might be refused by particular carriers.)

A temporary travel document (as mentioned in the last paragraph of this Answer) will certainly be accepted by the airline for a flight direct to India, and by Indian Immigration upon landing. But If your flight itinerary has an intermediate stop or layover, all bets are off — the airline will want be satisfied that you can enter the country of any intermediate stop. Without satisfying the entry requirements of the intermediate stop(s), the airline will not permit you to board the flight to that intermediate stop.

Can you state even a single airline that requires a passport with at least 3-6 months validity to book a ticket?  This is simply not a thing.  A passport isn't even requires to purchase a ticket.

@Doc I can't remember now, it's not in my records, because I had to book with a different airline. It was some Asian LCC, I think. But yes, I was unable to book an international flight on the website, because my passport didn't have enough validity time, and the system enforced it.

@Therac Even if that were the case for visitors from foreign countries, it would not apply to citizens returning to their country of citizenship.
